# Permutations without repeating myself

Tags: algorithms, permutations

This may be a quite simple question, but there we go.

Imagine that I've got a sequence $s = [s_1, s_2, \dots, s_n]$. I want to generate programatically a new random permutation $s'$ of $s$ so that $\forall i \in [1,n],\; s[i] \neq s'[i]$, of, what is the same, none of the values of the new permutation coincide 1-1 with the values of the previous one.

For instance, for $s = [1,2,3,4]$, $s' = [2,3,4,1]$ is a desired permutation because $s'$ is a permutation of $s$ and $2 \neq 1$, $2\neq 3$, and so on.

I know that the Fiser-Yates produces random permutation, but you cannot force the requirement that $s[i] \neq s'[i]$ for all $i$'s.

Thank you.

**Edit:** apparently I'm asking for how to generate a derangement with uniform probability distribution.

Comment: Two sequences can be different while representing the same permutation. I am not sure about what you are asking.

Comment: So the question is how to generate a derangement with uniform probability distribution?

Comment: @PeterTaylor exactly

Answer (score 1):

One way to generate a random derangement $\sigma$ of a set $S$ of $n$ letters is based on the [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements) $!n = (n-1)(!(n-1) + !(n-2)$.  First compute the derangement numbers $!k$ for $1 \le k \le n$.
Choose $\sigma(s_1)$ uniformly from $S \backslash \{s_1\}$.  With probability $!(n-2)/(!(n-1)+!(n-2))$, let $\sigma(\sigma(s_1)) = s_1$, and the rest of $\sigma$ is a derangement of the remaining $n-2$
letters $S \backslash \{s_1, \sigma(s_1)\}$.  Otherwise, recursively take a derangement of 
$\tau$ of $S \backslash \{s_1\}$; let $\sigma(\tau^{-1}(\sigma(s_1))) = s_1$, otherwise $\sigma(i) = \tau(i)$.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random derangement (that's a permutation with no fixed points), then multiply it by $s$ to obtain $s'$.